# how to make a button responsive which is placed on the image in html?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a *banner-image*, on that image I've placed  a *link*. This page is not getting aligned properly when I *zoom-in* or *zoom-out* the browser window or when I resize it.

The link is not getting aligned properly with respect to the image as it was showing in the default view(100% zoom ).

How to make this link responsive? I want the **Read More** button to be aligned exactly below the text **Driving Value creation with .....** text, and the **Read More** link to be responsive with respect to the image on which it is present. How can I do that?

Here's my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/scnaffaa)

```
   <p class="homeImageLink">
       <span><a href= "#" class="full_close">Read More</a></span>
   </p>
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/scnaffaa/1) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work, but I think it would:

```
.image_container span
{
    margin-left:-100px;

}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/scnaffaa/4/)

[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/scnaffaa/5/)

Comment: you just copied my **Fiddle** !! and you still not sure about your answer ;)

Comment: check it my first answer sir@vivekkupadhyay

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak your css so that the positioning is a bit more clear, I've [fixed it somewhat here](http://jsfiddle.net/scnaffaa/12/).

The important parts are here:

```
.image_container {
    position: relative;
}   

.homeImageLink {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    right: 3%;
}
```

On the container, `position: relative;` means that any internal positioning will work from this container. Any positioning apart from static would do here and it's important no intermediate elements in the tree have position set or it will work from that element instead.

The the link container itself is `position: absolute;` with `%` values used to keep it proportional to the size of the container. Note also that `right` is used instead of `left` so the element appears relative to the right of the container. Now it will never go off the right hand side of the image.

To make this clearer I've removed all the other css from the example and as you can see it still demonstrates the effect you desire.